# selenium scraping data using children of elements

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Hi i'm trying to scrape some data from a live stocks website. I want to display the companies name and stock price, %change ect. The details of 25 companies are shown per page, and these details follow the same format, one row of data comes under the  tag, have the same css selector and then the rest of the elements e.g. Name of the company share price, %change ect are children of that tag. Since all data follows the same format, my question is how do i filter through each  tag displaying data for that row?

I thought about:

using a for loop to find the elements by class name (since they all have the same class) and then cycle through these but I don't how to select a child of that class:

Here' the html code:
[image]

[image]

Here's the link to the site
https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/most-active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here ya go man! I had similar issues when trying to scrape data from a similar stock site

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

url = "https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/most-active"
uClient = uReq(url)
html_page = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')
full_table = soup.find_all("tr", class_="simpTblRow")

for tr in full_table:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [i.text for i in td]
    print(row)
```

You can make your own data structure to hold each of the printed values, it runs with this output (without labels, the output looks confusing but you can look at the site for reference)

```
['ICON.L', 'Iconic Labs Plc', '0.0132', '0.0000', '0.00%', '1.291B', '412.755M', 
'1.299M', 'N/A', '']
['SYME.L', 'Supply@ME Capital plc', '0.8020', '+0.2320', '+40.70%', '1.145B', 
'173.333M', '262.694M', 'N/A', '']
['UJO.L', 'Union Jack Oil plc', '0.2925', '-0.0075', '-2.50%', '210.666M', '154.613M', 
'45.165M', 'N/A', '']
['TOM.L', 'TomCo Energy Plc', '0.8750', '+0.0750', '+9.37%', '197.389M', '49.702M', 
'5.894M', 'N/A', '']
['PREM.L', 'Premier African Minerals Limited', '0.0680', '-0.0045', '-6.21%', 
'193.547M', '136.558M', '8.542M', 'N/A', '']
['COPL.L', 'Canadian Overseas Petroleum Limited', '0.4000', '-0.0200', '-4.76%', 
'139.094M', '211.933M', '9.549M', 'N/A', '']
['MSMN.L', 'Mosman Oil And Gas Limited', '0.1800', '+0.0200', '+12.50%', '136.04M', 
'51.481M', '2.854M', 'N/A', '']
['VAST.L', 'Vast Resources plc', '0.2100', '-0.0090', '-4.11%', '133.599M', 
'243.076M', '25.673M', 'N/A', '']
['UKOG.L', 'UK Oil & Gas Investments PLC', '0.2250', '+0.0150', '+7.14%', '114.909M', 
'275.501M', '24.974M', 'N/A', '']
['7DIG.L', '7digital Group plc', '2.8000', '-0.3000', '-9.68%', '111.529M', '23.568M', 
'68.752M', 'N/A', '']
['ALBA.L', 'Alba Mineral Resources PLC', '0.0925', '-0.0125', '-11.90%', '99.299M', 
'39.579M', '4.472M', 'N/A', '']
['LLOY.L', 'Lloyds Banking Group plc', '28.18', '-0.44', '-1.54%', '98.424M', 
'263.235M', '19.948B', '70.46', '']
['KOD.L', 'Kodal Minerals Plc', '0.0475', '0.0000', '0.00%', '111.583M', '75.563M', 
'5.278M', 'N/A', '']
['UFO.L', 'Alien Metals Limited', '0.3600', '+0.0500', '+16.13%', '84.677M', 
'52.319M', '8.516M', 'N/A', '']
['EDL.L', 'Edenville Energy Plc', '0.0500', '-0.0025', '-4.76%', '80.171M', '47.879M', 
'4.073M', 'N/A', '']
['EQT.L', 'EQTEC plc', '0.5300', '+0.0650', '+13.98%', '73.296M', '144.02M', 
'36.929M', 'N/A', '']
['BOIL.L', 'Baron Oil Plc', '0.1000', '-0.0025', '-2.44%', '73.45M', '71.853M', 
'4.426M', 'N/A', '']
['BREE.L', 'Breedon Group plc', '83.20', '+2.20', '+2.72%', '63.05M', '4.616M', 
'1.403B', '43.79', '']
['AMGO.L', 'Amigo Holdings PLC', '9.30', '+0.55', '+6.29%', '62.892M', '20.841M', 
'44.206M', 'N/A', '']
['INSP.L', 'Inspirit Energy Holdings Plc', '0.0800', '+0.0025', '+3.23%', '61.622M', 
'73.243M', '2.323M', 'N/A', '']
['TRAF.L', 'Trafalgar Property Group plc', '0.2000', '0.0000', '0.00%', '55.959M', 
'40.707M', '2.85M', 'N/A', '']
['RBD.L', 'Reabold Resources plc', '0.7300', '-0.0350', '-4.58%', '51.697M', 
'23.499M', '51.808M', 'N/A', '']
['CPI.L', 'Capita plc', '28.70', '-7.18', '-20.01%', '48.494M', '12.711M', '478.994M', 
'N/A', '']
['GGP.L', 'Greatland Gold plc', '12.20', '-0.80', '-6.15%', '44.829M', '33.176M', 
'461.41M', 'N/A', '']
['SRES.L', 'Sunrise Resources plc', '0.3000', '-0.0100', '-3.23%', '39.45M', 
'15.895M', '9.963M', 'N/A', '']
```

Comment: btw, on the line soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser'), you should replace 'html.parser' with lxml, it will run more efficiently

Comment: wow thankyou so much, i've never used beautiful soup before and this just worked like a charm thanks.

Comment: could you explain how this works please, because I may need document my work. Thanks

Comment: im trying to assign variable names to each variable on the list

Comment: Yeah basically the table "rows" your trying to scrape are all tr tags, so BS4 scrapes the page in the .find_all() method, these rows also have a class name of: "simpTblRow" so I specified for soup to look for that. From there each tr tag has a child td tag that holds the text values for each row segment, so that's where the for loop is implemented to find all the children and get their individual text values.

Comment: One thing you could also do is enumerate each time row takes on a new value, and create multiple statements based on the enumerated 'i' value, placing each element into a labeled dictionary for easy readability.

Answer (score 1):

```
table =[]
#Get the total number of rows for your table on page
tableRows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='scr-res-table']//tr")
for i in range (2, len(tableRows)+1): #Starting from 2 as 1st row is column caption
    rowList  = []
    #Title scrapping is different from others as it is under tag a under td
    titlexPath = "//div[@id='scr-res-table']//tr["+str(i)+"]//td[1]/a"
    rowList.append(driver.find_element_by_xpath(titlexPath).text) 

    #Assuming you need data from column Name to PE ratio.
    for j in range(2,10):
        dataXpath = "//div[@id='scr-res-table']//tr["+str(i)+"]//td["+str(j)+"]"
        rowList.append(driver.find_element_by_xpath(dataXpath).text)

    table.append(rowList)
print(table)
```

**Note** : I have used List to store data from table on webpage. you can use Panda libraries for clean and easy storage and manipulation of data

Comment: hi thanks for your help, i am trying to integrate your code but there's a problem with the line ```row_+str(i)``` the error is 'cannot assign to operator.

Comment: Ah!!! I made a mistake. Anyway it was just the name of temporary list. I have updated code. Please try now.