# Scraping options price from yahoo finance using BeautifulSoup and find

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, find, xlwings

I am building an MS Excel document to get stock and option prices from Yahoo finance, ariva etc. I am using xlwings and BeautifulSoup to get the data.

Everything works fine, I get stock prices from Yahoo and I also get stock/German option prices from ariva directly to Excel. Unfortunately, the option prices (not stock prices) are more difficult to get.

I am using this code (e.g. ticker is 'NVDA', date is '44211' (for 15/1/2021) and option_name is 'NVDA210115C00210000'):

```
import xlwings as xw
import bs4 as bs
import requests 

@xw.func
def get_stock(ticker,date,option_name):
    url_base = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/'
    new_date = str(86400*(date-25569))
    src_base = requests.get(url_base+ticker+'/options?date='+new_date).text
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(src_base,'lxml')
```

This results in loading https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/NVDA/options?date=1610668800 (that works fine).

How do I get the option price for this option: NVDA210115C00210000? I tried:

```
    price = soup.find_all('div',attrs={'id':'Col1-1-OptionContracts-Proxy'})[0].find(attrs={'class':'data-col2'}).get_text()

    return[price]
```

But it only returns the price of the first option on this page.

See picture: [Yahoo Finance Code and option price](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYkkm.jpg) I want the 324,37.

Somehow, I have to find the place of 'NVDA210115C00210000' and THEN get the text of data-col2. I just startet using Python two days ago and I am not a progammer, but I think it shouldn't be that difficult.

How can I use the 'find' to find that place and THEN get the price?

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63477842/selenium-scraping-data-using-children-of-elements help?

Comment: Has it worked now?

Answer (score 0):

You have many errors,

```
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(src_base,'lxml')
```

should be:

```
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(src_base.content,'lxml')
```

It's `.content` you are missing.

What I done was instead find the the table row:     `table_data = soup.find('tr',{'data-reactid':'200'})` then found the data in that row     `option_price = table_data.find('td', {'data-reactid':'206'}).text`

```
def get_stock(ticker,date,option_name):
    url_base = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/'
    new_date = str(86400*(date-25569))
    src_base = requests.get(url_base+ticker+'/options?date='+new_date)
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(src_base.content,'lxml')

    table_data = soup.find('tr',{'data-reactid':'200'})
    option_price = table_data.find('td', {'data-reactid':'206'}).text

    print(option_price)

get_stock('NVDA',44211,'NVDA210115C00210000')

>>> 407.35
```

HTML Code

```html
<tr class="data-row7 Bgc($hoverBgColor):h BdT Bdc($seperatorColor) H(33px) in-the-money Bgc($hoverBgColor)" data-reactid="200">
 <td class="data-col3 Ta(end) Pstart(7px)" data-reactid="206">407.35</td>
```